# Back: update parametrizado o update general

Tags: rest, backend

estoy realizando un ejercicio de back REST, con la finalidad de practicar y mejorar conceptos en el cual se asignan citas donde tengo los siguientes atributos:

- tipoCita
- estadoCita
- fechaHora
- medicoId
- pacienteId

y tengo la duda de si parametrizar las actualizaciones a estos atributos de la entidad con la finalidad de realizar un seguimiento de las modificaciones que se hacen. o simplemente realizar las actualizaciones como un update general a las entidad que pues reflejan lo que hay en la base de datos.

Por ejemplo, si desean actualizar el medicoId que exista un endpoint de la siguiente manera

-> api/asignarMedico/{citaId}/{medicoId}

O en su defecto pasar los path como parámetros.